# Is it appropriate to informally address my supervisor in the thesis acknowledgements?

Tags: thesis, advisor, etiquette, acknowledgement, professionalism

All of the acknowledgment examples I have read online address the supervisor with formal title and full name (i.e. Prof WhatNot). In my case, I'd rather use the first name only ("nickname" actually), is that so uncommon? I should probably ask him, but I wanted to understand what is the general opinion.

Comment: What country are we talking about here?

Comment: One of the reasons for using the formal name is that readers can find who your supervisor was and check his/her academic record - a good supervisor may add weight to your thesis. You could write "thanks to Prof. Nicholas ("Nicky") Whatnot..." which balances formality and informality.

Comment: The name of the supervisor is stated on the title page

Answer (score 3):

This is going to vary a lot by the country and customs of your university, and your relationship with your advisor. But I'd say, if you relationship with your advisor is good, then in the UK it would *not* be seen as out of order to refer to your supervisor as informally as you like in the acknowledgements sections of your thesis. In the theses I've read, these things are often a lot like best man speeches - often written in a jovial and cheeky style, while staying just the right side of the appropriateness line, but also often cloyingly sentimental at the same time.

Comment: It would probably need to be changed for publication, though.

Comment: theses are only "published" here in that they go into the university library and can be requested through inter-library loans serivce and the abstract goes into the index of thesis abstracts. They are very rarely read (a common game is to put a £20 in the thesis and come back in 10 years to see if its still there). People publish books *based* on their theses, but its not just the theses with a ISBN slapped on it.

Comment: I suspect undergraduates go through the theses in the library looking for those. I know I would.

Comment: Clever undergrads deserve it! And maybe they'll accidentally reads something and learn something at the same time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, but this is only one person's opinion, it is better to be a bit formal in such a document. But standards can vary. Your best bet is to ask him how he would like to be acknowledged. You can specifically ask if an informal ack would be ok or not.

But there are a few very prominent people who are known professionally by a nickname and it that case, a commonly used form is probably fine.